# Readout the query in Google Custom Search Engine

Tags: google-custom-search

I have implemented the Google Custom Search Engine (two-column type) on my website and everything works fine. Now I want to change the background of my website depending on the query which has been typed in the input box. How can I get this query from the input box after it was written in it?
Once I could get it out of the input box, I could compare it to a number of fixed keywords and change the background depending on the match.

I tried already this:

*var query = google.search.cse.element.getElement("search").getInputQuery();*

but it doesn't work.

I have looked already on the Google Developpers site:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element

This is my code so far:

```
    <script>
            var query = google.search.cse.element.getElement("search").getInputQuery();
            var wallpaper = document.getElementById("background")
            if (query.localeCompare("hardware") == 0)
                {wallpaper.id = "hardware";}
            else if (query.localeCompare("software") == 0)
                {wallpaper.id = "software";}
    </script>

<gcse:searchbox gname="search"></gcse:searchbox>
<gcse:searchresults gname="search"></gcse:searchresults>
```

Anyone having any idea?